# Position of TVS diode in Ethernet application

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, diodes, ethernet, esd

I'm going through this [appnote](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/00002157B.pdf).

My question is based on Figure 1 on page 1 of the datasheet.
Am I correct in understanding that it is not correct to move the TVS diode (DBI) from the PHY side of the transformer to the RJ45 side?
I feel that it is not right, based on the resistance value and capacitance of the capacitor between the transformer and RJ45 specified in the Hardware Check List.

I plan to use LAN8740A in the application. The above question is to make provision to protect the device from ESD issues.

Comment: The appnote is pretty explicit. Besides, what are you wanting to protect? The transformer? Or the infinitely more susceptible PHY chip?  Rather than ‘feel’ if it is correct or incorrect, work the numbers to give you an answer rather than guess.

Comment: The appnote is not about ESD.

Comment: @Justme, could you tell me which position of the ESD would be helpful?

Comment: @Kartman, I am trying to protect the PHY chip

Comment: Many parts have built-in ESD protection so first of all you'll have to settle for a level (described in EN 61000-4-2) for contact and air discharges, then check if all parts fulfill that requirement or if there's a need for additional external protection. And TVS is just one way to solve it.

Comment: Do you need support for PoE or not?

Comment: @Justme, yes I would need PoE support

Comment: The application note, at a first glance, is very correct and practical: why should you change topology?

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that it is not correct to move the TVS diode (DBI) from the PHY side of the transformer to the RJ45 side? I feel that it is not right, based on the resistance value and capacitance of the capacitor between the transformer and RJ45 specified in the Hardware Check List @LuC

Comment: TVS on the media side would seem to invite short-circuit currents on hot-plugging. Putting it behind the transformer introduces some impedance (leakage inductance, resistance), and possibly saturation if the transient has long duration.  Clamping voltage then is more critical as there's little impedance between TVS and PHY.  Probably using a low-clamping snapback diode such as Semtech makes would be advisable.

Comment: @TimWilliams, thank you for your comment. So, you suggest to place the TVS in the location indicated in the app note itself, right? Also, is this TVS Diode OK?  https://semtech.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#E0000000JelG/a/2R0000001TBb/1Sb_xwpUbvH6q70WnqQwnuIuQfNX7THrFXZCKGHIIn8

Comment: I generally agree with the appnote, yes. That's probably an adequate TVS, yes. Oh, was your PHY a GbE style (H bridge output, no VCC bias to centertap) (see datasheet Fig.1)? You'll need a higher nominal voltage rating if 10/100 style (CT wired to VCC).

Comment: @TimWilliams, LAN8740A is the PHY. Also, is the part that I suggested fine?

Comment: Yes, I saw that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144843/discussion-between-newbie-and-tim-williams).