# Hot-plugging current - TVS and ethernet

Tags: voltage, ethernet, poe, rj45, hot-plug

My question is based on this question over [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/660064/position-of-tvs-diode-in-ethernet-application)

In one of the comments, it is mentioned,

"TVS on the media side would seem to invite short-circuit currents on hot-plugging. Putting it behind the transformer introduces some impedance (leakage inductance, resistance), and possibly saturation if the transient has long duration. Clamping voltage then is more critical as there's little impedance between TVS and PHY. Probably using a low-clamping snapback diode such as Semtech makes would be advisable"

Can someone please tell me how the short circuit current is generated on hot plugging?

Comment: That appnote is not about Ethernet itself but about hot plugging conmections with Power over Ethernet, and more about passive PoE than standard PoE.

Comment: @Justme, Ok, could you please clarify on that comment on how hot plugging generates short circuit?

Comment: Did you read the appnote linked in the question, which has multiple pages about how transients happen on Ethernet and how to handle them?

Comment: @Justme, I am still reading. But I am searching for "hot plugging" term in the app note but unable to find it.

Comment: That app note doesn't use the phrase "hot plugging": it describes the voltages which might be on the wire (table 3) when the cable is inserted/removed, while being aware that the connections may bounce and won't be simultaneous.  If you've got voltage on the wire during connection, you can consider that to be "hot plugging" (or unplugging).

Comment: @jonathanjo, thank you for the comment. Can you please tell me how the short circuit current is generated on hot plugging?

Comment: The comment you quote is also taken out of context. Generally when plugging in a PoE cable, you would hopefully not get short circuits, but just normal inrush currents. A short circuit with passive PoE would just melt transformer wires and it would act as a fuse. Like when you plug in your computer into mains socket, there is a huge inrush current of several if not tens of amps to charge the capacitors.

Comment: It's not my field of expertise, but my understanding is the comment is suggesting that putting the TVS on the media pair means that connection voltage spikes would cause the TVS to short the media pair and thus bring high current.

Comment: @jonathanjo It's useless to speculate what the out-of-context comment really means. The TVS on the media pair would just not protect the PHY from transients that happen when plugging in a passive PoE. It would not also short anything.

Comment: @Justme, just to clarify two points: 1. When it is mentioned, "It is not appropriate to move the TVS diode from his PHY side of the transformer to the RJ45 side."

Does that mean his TVS on the RJ45 side is not suitable because he doesn't protect the PHY from the transients that occur when connecting passive PoE?



2. When you mention, "it would not be short anything."

Does that mean the TVS will not cause a short circuit current when hotplugging?

Comment: To clarify, "short circuit current" means just that: short circuit in some instant.  Typically an inrush current spike rises from zero quickly up to some current limited by element impedances, then falls as capacitors charge.  In situations where instantaneous current matters (like transformer saturation), it isn't important whether that current is sustained (a literal short circuit) or transient (inrush).

Comment: These dynamics are likely evident if you simply put together a simulation of the system in question, and probe for peak currents in various branches.  Mind to account for mismatched switching times, as contacts will not, in general, mate simultaneously when a connector is plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

> Ok, could you please clarify on that comment on how hot plugging generates short circuit?

There can be a lot of potential between the cable you're plugging in and ground. The cable jacket can be electrostatically charged for example.

Even a fairly small charge - too small to feel as a "zap" - will turn the TVS protection on. But at the same time you're plugging PoE circuits into a TVS that's temporarily shorted by the foregoing electrostatic discharge. If the PoE is passive, you're shorting it with a crowbar that drops at most a volt across at 1A.

Just because the TVS "turns on" at a high voltage doesn't mean that it's transparent to low voltages at that time much: it turns *on* at that voltage. It will stay conducting for a while even with the current removed, and pushing any current through it will prolong its turn-off. That current can come from any available low-voltage source.

A hot plug means that there's a "full power" supply sitting at the other side -typical of passive PoEs, with smoothing capacitors charged, and all that. Last thing you'd want is to have a conducting TVS be on the other side when the connection is made via RJ-45. It may draw a spark, leave some erosion on the plug and the jack, and cause the power supply's capacitors to discharge into a short circuit. Not very nice.

Comment: Sorry but Ethernet is a galvanically isolated inteface with transformer coupling. There can be beyond 1000V on each side of the transformer and that's OK. However plugging in the connector with passive PoE so that only one wire of the pair mates before the second, your PoE inrush through one half of the transistor couples to PHY. And to be fair, the point of the TVS was to be on the PHY side, not cable side, and the question is about how surges happen on plugging the cable, which is explained in the appnote in the linked question. Same way as plugging in a mains plug or DC plug to charge caps.