# Question of Ethernet PoE and TVS protection

Tags: voltage, current, esd, transient, tvs

My question is based on this question over [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/660064/position-of-tvs-diode-in-ethernet-application)

Asking this question here since I didn't receive a clear answer that clarified my confusions on TVS for PoE applications.

As far as I understand, the app note describes to place the TVS diode after the transformer (close to the RJ-45 connector).

My questions are:

1. When it is mentioned, "It is not appropriate to move the TVS diode from his PHY side of the transformer to the RJ45 side."

Does that mean his TVS on the RJ45 side is not suitable because he doesn't protect the PHY from the transients that occur when connecting passive PoE?

2. The TVS will not cause a short circuit current when hotplugging?

Comment: You already have one similar question about the same question. Why a new question about same subject?

Comment: @Justme, I did not get clarity from the comments section. Hence, asking a new one. Could you please clarify better.

Comment: @TimWilliams, I'm not able to get clarity from that link. It also involves 1 of your comment on that link. Could you explain a bit more on your comment, "TVS on the media side would seem to invite short-circuit currents on hot-plugging. Putting it behind the transformer introduces some impedance (leakage inductance, resistance), and possibly saturation if the transient has long duration. Clamping voltage then is more critical as there's little impedance between TVS and PHY. " - Taken from: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/660064/position-of-tvs-diode-in-ethernet-application

Comment: @Freshman - Please edit/improve your previous question instead of repeating most/all of it again here. That is part of the Stack Exchange "philosophy" i.e. edit questions to make them answerable. || You have added a comment to *that* question which effectively duplicates *this* question. Don't do that, please *edit the question* to clarify it instead. If you want to notify a previous comment writer about the question being edited, you can write a short `@username` comment saying something like "I have tried to clarify the question in response to your comment, please can you review it".